# How schedule a job run at 8 PM CET using schedule package in python

Tags: python-3.x, scheduling, job-scheduling

I want to schedule a python script to run at every workday (monday to friday) at 8 PM CET. How can this be done.

```
   import schedule
    import time

    def task():
        print("Job Running")

    schedule.every(10).minutes.do(task)
```

How can this be done.

Answer (score 1):

*Is there a reason you cannot use either crontab or Windows Task Scheduler to schedule your jobs?*

**Answer One:**

The `schedule` module documentation does not indicate a simple way to schedule a python script to run every workday (monday to friday) at 8 PM CET.

Plus the use of timezones is not supported in the `schedule` module.
Reference: [4.1.3 Does schedule support timezones?](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/schedule/stable/schedule.pdf)

Here is way to schedule a job to run every workday at 20:00 (8pm) using the `schedule` module.

```
import schedule
import time

def schedule_actions():

  # Every Monday task() is called at 20:00
  schedule.every().monday.at('20:00').do(task)

  # Every Tuesday task() is called at 20:00
  schedule.every().tuesday.at('20:00').do(task)

  # Every Wednesday task() is called at 20:00
  schedule.every().wednesday.at('20:00').do(task)

  # Every Thursday task() is called at 20:00
  schedule.every().thursday.at('20:00').do(task)

  # Every Friday task() is called at 20:00
  schedule.every().friday.at('20:00').do(task)

  # Checks whether a scheduled task is pending to run or not
  while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)


def task():
  print("Job Running")


schedule_actions()
```

**Answer Two:**

I spent some additional time looking at using a scheduler inside a python script. During my research, I discovered the Python library -- Advanced Python Scheduler (`APScheduler`).
This library seems to be very flexible based on the module's [documentation.](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

Here is an example that I put together for you, which worked in my testing.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BlockingScheduler

# BlockingScheduler: use when the scheduler is the only thing running in your process
scheduler = BlockingScheduler()

# Other scheduler types are listed here: 
# https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html

# Define the function that is to be executed
# at a scheduled time
def job_function ():
   print ('text')

# Schedules the job_function to be executed Monday through Friday at 20:00 (8pm)
scheduler.add_job(job_function, 'cron', day_of_week='mon-fri', hour=20, minute=00)

# If you desire an end_date use this
# scheduler.add_job(job_function, 'cron', day_of_week='mon-fri', hour=20, minute=00, end_date='2019-12-31')

# Start the scheduler
scheduler.start()
```