# How to restart a Python script in Windows 10 (Close existing one and open another)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to restart python script at 12:00AM everyday. I can open another script from the existing python script, but it will open too many python scripts.

I want to close the existing python script and open another one. How Can I do it? It's not a duplicate.

Comment: It's not a duplicate, but your question is so imprecise, that it's quite impossible to answer. Please give information on what you've tried, so others see what you are trying to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How schedule a job run at 8 PM CET using schedule package in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55466212/how-schedule-a-job-run-at-8-pm-cet-using-schedule-package-in-python)

Comment: @SimonFink Just like we close a program and then start it again manually. I want to do the same. It will be good, If I could do it within the python program itself.

Comment: My program runs for 24 hours using a loop, then we need to start it again.

Comment: This is not what you do with Python, but OS level functionality, e.g. crontab on linux systems. Take a look at the link from @MauriceMeyer! The top answer contains a lot of useful information.